# Significado de "BASTA DE # DE HAMBRE"

Tags: significado, preposiciones, símbolos

Veo en la imagen que encabeza [esta noticia](https://elpais.com/elpais/2019/02/18/planeta_futuro/1550491014_727538.html) la siguiente pancarta:

[image: pancarta]

Texto:

> BASTA
>      <sup><sub>DE # DE</sub></sup>
>   HAMBRE

A primera vista lo he leído como *"BASTA DE HAMBRE"*, pero **me llama la atención la aparición por duplicado de la preposición "DE", así como el uso del símbolo `#` en medio**. ¿Por qué está escrito así?

En inglés a veces se usa `#` en lugar de *number*, sobre todo en contextos técnicos o contables ([ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507011/max-of-elements-and-dimensions-supported-by-each-data-container-in-matlab), [ejemplo](https://mcpactions.com/faq/)). ¿Es el del cartel un uso similar, queriendo decir entonces algo como *"BASTA DE [¿miles? ¿millones?] DE HAMBRE"*? ¿O es tan solo un simple adorno para rellenar la línea central del cartel y que no ponga solo "DE"? ¿O tienen el símbolo `#` o la construcción "DE # DE" algún significado particular en español, quizá regional de Argentina?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Todo indica que la duplicación de la palabra *DE* es un error en la confección del cartel, y que el signo *#* indica un *hashtag* de Twitter (un prefijo que se usa convencionalmente para indicar que la palabra que sigue, o conjunto de palabras unidas entre sí, es un tema central o relacionado a lo que se está compartiendo). La práctica de incorporar *hashtags* a las campañas políticas "en la vida real" (vale decir, en medios diferentes a la propia red social Twitter) es muy común en Argentina, no sé si en otros países: la presencia del símbolo *#* denota que se trata de un eslogan o tema unificador, sea que aparezca en un zócalo de televisión o escrito a mano en un pedazo de cartón.

En estos últimos días hubo manifestaciones masivas, organizadas por movimientos sociales y partidarios como los mencionados en la nota, en cuya difusión se usó el *hashtag* **#BastaDeHambre**. El mismo lo viene usando el Movimiento Evita (citado en la nota) en otras manifestaciones de oposición al gobierno.

[image]

[image]